# How to remove the end of the "s" in partial "_error_messages"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to remove the end of the "s" in partial "_error_messages".

```
<% if event.errors.any? %>  
<div id="errorExplanation">  
  <h2> В форме обнаружено <%= pluralize(event.errors.count, "ошибки") %>:</h2>  
  <ul>  
  <% event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>  
    <li><%= msg %></li>  
  <% end %>  
  </ul>  
</div>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: which 's'? There's lots in that code.

Comment: when the browser displays an "2 error"s" prohibited this record from being saved", I want to write in their mother language and the end of "s" there is no more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do...

```
pluralize(event.errors.count, "ошибка", "ошибки")
```

It will use the singular term if one, and the plural term otherwise.